# R: strsplit on backslash (\)

Tags: regex, r, strsplit

I am trying to extract the part of the string before the first backslash but I can't seem to get it tot work properly.

I have tried multiple ways of getting it to work, based on the manual page for strsplit and after searching online.

In my actual situation the strings are in a dataframe which I get from a database connection but I can simplify the situation with the following:

```
> strsplit("BLAAT1\022E:\\BLAAT2\\BLAAT3","\\",fixed=TRUE)
[[1]]
[1] "BLAAT1\022E:" "BLAAT2"      "BLAAT3"  

> strsplit("BLAAT1\022E:\\BLAAT2\\BLAAT3","\\",fixed=FALSE)
Error in strsplit("BLAAT1\022E:\\BLAAT2\\BLAAT3", "\\", fixed = FALSE) : 
  invalid regular expression '\', reason 'Trailing backslash'

> strsplit("BLAAT1\022E:\\BLAAT2\\BLAAT3","\\\\",fixed=TRUE)
[[1]]
[1] "BLAAT1\022E:\\BLAAT2\\BLAAT3"

> strsplit("BLAAT1\022E:\\BLAAT2\\BLAAT3","\\\\",fixed=FALSE)
[[1]]
[1] "BLAAT1\022E:" "BLAAT2"       "BLAAT3"
```

The expected output would also split on the \ between BLAAT1 and 022E:

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want 4 elements as expected output or just `BLAAT` and `02E:\\BLATT2\\BLAAT3` as the 2nd split.  BTW, `\022` it is a unicode symbol

Comment: You have ASCII characters here, does `strsplit("BLAAT1\022E:\\BLAAT2\\BLAAT3","[[:cntrl:]]")` gives you what you want?

Comment: `"\022"` is a character.

Comment: Or `strsplit("BLAAT1\022E:\\BLAAT2\\BLAAT3","[^[:print:]]")`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you use a regex with `strsplit` function, a literal backslash can be coded as two literal backslashes (as a literal `\` is a special regex metacharacter that is used to form regex escapes, like `\d`, `\w`, etc.), but since R string literals support string escape sequences (like `"\r"` for carriage return, `"\n"` for a newline char) a literal backslash needs to be defined with a double backslash.

So, `"\\"` is a literal `\`, and a regex pattern to match a literal backslash char, being `\\`, should be coded with 4 backslashes, `"\\\\"`.

Here is a regex that you can use: it splits at `\` and a [non-printable character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html):

```
strsplit("BLAAT1\022E:\\BLAAT2\\BLAAT3","\\\\|[^[:print:]]",fixed=FALSE)
# [1] "BLAAT1" "E:"     "BLAAT2" "BLAAT3"
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/9ciDoP)

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize the \022 was a non-printable character.